# How do i filter hyperlinks in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some rows with hyperlinks and without hyperlinks
I want to filter only hyperlink data. Thank you.

Comment: Which column?.................

Comment: 1st column A then filter them to B

Comment: Answer is: "Filter By Color" blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This copies the hyperlinks with link to column B as you mentioned in the comments section:

```
Sub Macro1()
    cnt = 1
    For Each cell In Range("A:A")
        If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            Range("B" & cnt) = cell
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("B" & cnt), cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

High-light (select) the cells in column A you wish to filter (not including the header row) and run this small macro:

```
Sub HyperPicker()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question as originally written in a nice clean loop.